# WPF control listview

Tags: c#, wpf

```
ID     |  Name     | Address
----------------------------------
1      | Gia Ngoc  | Vietnamses 
2      | Jerry     | US
```

How to add lines like in the diagram above to a ListView?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Grid lines in WPF ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138628/grid-lines-in-wpf-listview)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** If you mean to add a visual seperators between the columns you probably need to implement your own view by inheriting from [`ViewBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbase.aspx) since the `GridView` does not seem to be very customizable.

(*Below i assumed that you wanted to add rows*)

---

You need to set the [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx).[`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.view.aspx) to a [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx) and define columns for it.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Isn't he asking how to add vertical and horizontal grid lines, rather than how to add columns?  Also, no, you do not need to populate the ListView via ItemsSource to use column bindings: you can still use the Items collection.

Comment: Who knows, possibly. What you say about the items makes sense, but adding clr-objects as solid items in XAML is something one normally just does not do.

Comment: You can example, write code on file xaml.cs Add a line directly in code

Comment: Which is also something you normally do not do. That aside, What was your question? Sperator lines or columns?

Comment: How can to create a sperator line or columns